# Is it possible to map stored procedure result with a model that is not an EF Core entity model, without add this custom model into dbcontext.cs file?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, .net-6.0

The following code is working only if first line of code is provide in `dbcontext.cs` file. Actually I am using code first approach and `dbcontext.cs` file is auto generated file based on core entity models and when I will regenerate the `dbcontext.cs` it will remove other models automatically.

`DbContext`:

```
public DbSet<ModelSpDto> ModelSp { get; set; } 
// I need to remove it from dbcontext and use it somewhere else.
```

`Controller`:

```
var myQuery = _context.Set<ModelSpDto>()
                      .FromSqlRaw($"EXECUTE dbo.storedProcedure (request.UserId)");
query = query.OrderByDescending (x => x. DateCreated).ToList();

// Pagination
IPagedList<ModelSpDto> PagingData = await query.ToPagedListAsync (pageNumber: request.PageNumber, pageSize: request.PageSize);

// Response
response.PagingData = PagingData.ToMapped PagedList<ModelSpDto, ModelSp2Dto>(_mapper);
```

Comment: You can do this with EF Core 8, yes

Comment: @ErikEJ can you please answer with some working code in EF Core 8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible with EF Core 8 and the SqlQuery method:

sample:

```
 var start = new DateOnly(2022, 1, 1);
 var end = new DateOnly(2023, 1, 1);
 var postsIn2022 =
    await context.Database
    .SqlQuery<BlogPost>($"SELECT * FROM Posts as p WHERE p.PublishedOn >= {start} AND p.PublishedOn < {end}")
    .ToListAsync();
```